# How to properly / efficiently manage entity manager JPA Spring @Transactional for large datasets?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

I am attempting to insert ~57,000 entities in my database, but the insert method takes longer and longer as the loop progresses.  I have implemented batches of 25 - each time flushing, clearing, and closing the transaction (I'm pretty sure) without success. Is there something else I need to be doing in the code below to maintain the insert rate? I feel like it should not take 4+ hours to insert 57K records.

[Migrate.java]

This is the main class that loops through 'Xaction' entities and adds 'XactionParticipant' records based off each Xaction.

```
// Use hibernate cursor to efficiently loop through all xaction entities
String hql = "select xaction from Xaction xaction";
Query<Xaction> query = session.createQuery(hql, Xaction.class);
query.setFetchSize(100);
query.setReadOnly(true);
query.setLockMode("xaction", LockMode.NONE);
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

int count = 0;
Instant lap = Instant.now();
List<Xaction> xactionsBatch = new ArrayList<>();
while (results.next()) {
    count++;

    Xaction xaction = (Xaction) results.get(0);
    xactionsBatch.add(xaction);

    // save new XactionParticipants in batches of 25
    if (count % 25 == 0) {
        xactionParticipantService.commitBatch(xactionsBatch);
        float rate = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(lap, Instant.now()) / 25f / 1000;
        System.out.printf("Batch rate: %.4fs per xaction\n", rate);
        xactionsBatch = new ArrayList<>();
        lap = Instant.now();
    }
}
xactionParticipantService.commitBatch(xactionsBatch);
results.close();
```

[XactionParticipantService.java]

This service provides a method with "REQUIRES_NEW" in an attempt to close the transaction for each batch

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void commitBatch(List<Xaction> xactionBatch) {
    for (Xaction xaction : xactionBatch) {
        try {
            XactionParticipant xp = new XactionParticipant();
            // ... create xp based off Xaction info ...

            // Use native query for efficiency
            String nativeQueryStr = "INSERT INTO XactionParticipant .... xp info/data";
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQueryStr);
            q.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to update", e);
        }
    }
    // Clear just in case??
    em.flush();
    em.clear();
}
```

Comment: So many questions: Why do you need a cursor for inserts? And why do you think that a native insert query where you create the string new each time is faster than a prepared statement from the framework? Did you also measure the time that Java needs for its GC? Why do you create a new `ArrayList` inside the loop instead of clearing the existing one?

Comment: The cursor is because I can't load all 57K Xaction records into memory using a simple jpql query (the table has roughly 40 columns). Native query vs. Framework: I don't, hence the post - but I've tried both. I have not, but I'm not sure the calculation would help when garbage collection happens it would through the numbers off for maybe one or 2 batches - however the calculation is ever increasing.  Will change array to clear rather than "new"

Comment: do you create the `XactionParticipant` information only from data you query from the `Xaction` table before?

Comment: Curious, 100k in 10 minutes shoud be easy. Otherwise: If possible use a dblink in combination with native SQL like `INSERT INTO yourdb.. SELECT FROM remotedb`. Use multithreading. Use a jpa-fetch-profile. Disable the cache of the transations using transactionIsolation.

Comment: 57k / 4 hours are 14k in one hour. Makes 237 per minute. makes 4 per second. Thats slow.

Comment: The entity manager you flush and clear is a different one then the one you are using in your reading part. Hence the first level cache will fill. What you should do is clear the `session` inside the loop after the commit. You also want to increase the size as 25 isn't that big. Why use Hibernate/JPA if you are going to bypass it anyway with a native query? Finally optimize your batch settings for hibernate (align it with your batch size) and order insert/update statements that will make it a batch insert (although probably only if you use JPA/JPQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not clear what is the root cause of your performance problem: java memory consumption or db performance, please check some thoughts below:

1. The following code does not actually optimize memory consumption:

```java
String hql = "select xaction from Xaction xaction";
Query<Xaction> query = session.createQuery(hql, Xaction.class);
query.setFetchSize(100);
query.setReadOnly(true);
query.setLockMode("xaction", LockMode.NONE);
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

Since you are retrieving full-functional entities, those entities get stored in persistence context (session-level cache), and in order to free memory up you need to detach entity upon entity has been processed (i.e. after `xactionsBatch.add(xaction)` or `// ... create xp based off Xaction info ...`), otherwise at the end of processing you consume the same amount of memory as you were doing `List<> results = query.getResultList();`, and here I'm not sure what is better: consume all memory required at the start of transaction and release all other resources or keep cursor and jdbc connection open for 4 hours.

2. The following code does not actually optimize JDBC interactions:

```java
    for (Xaction xaction : xactionBatch) {
        try {
            XactionParticipant xp = new XactionParticipant();
            // ... create xp based off Xaction info ...

            // Use native query for efficiency
            String nativeQueryStr = "INSERT INTO XactionParticipant .... xp info/data";
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQueryStr);
            q.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to update", e);
        }
    }
```

yes, in general, JDBC should be faster than JPA API, however that is not your case - you are inserting records one-by-one instead of using batch inserts. In order to take advantage of batches your code should look like:

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void commitBatch(List<Xaction> xactionBatch) {
    session.doWork(connection -> {
        String insert = "INSERT INTO XactionParticipant VALUES (?, ?, ...)";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insert)) {
            for (Xaction xaction : xactionBatch) {
                ps.setString(1, "val1");
                ps.setString(2, "val2");
                ps.addBatch();
                ps.clearParameters();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    });
}
```

BTW, Hibernate may do the same if `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` is set to large enough positive integer and entities are properly designed (id generation is backed up by DB sequence and allocationSize is large enough)

Comment: For 1 you don't really need to detach, doing a `session.flush()` and `session.clear()` inside the for loop will solve that as well. The `em.flush`/`em.clear` in the method don't actually clear the session as it operates on a different instance due to the new transaction.

Comment: Many thanks for this well thought out answer.  I did not realize that the cursor approach wasn't saving me anything because of how I was using the "entity".

Comment: I sort of threw up my hands yesterday and created an sql script to loop through each Team with a cursor, then each Xaction wioth a cursor, then creating the XactionParticipant entry with several IF..THEN statements.  The result was an update that took 57 seconds.  smh.